# Hudson Error: Unable to call isArchivingDisabled. Invalid object ID

Tags: hudson

I get this error when building a project, that could be built without problems before:

[INFO] Trace
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to call isArchivingDisabled. Invalid object ID 5
    at hudson.remoting.RemoteInvocationHandler$RPCRequest.perform(RemoteInvocationHandler.java:268)
    at hudson.remoting.RemoteInvocationHandler$RPCRequest.call(RemoteInvocationHandler.java:255)
    at hudson.remoting.RemoteInvocationHandler$RPCRequest.call(RemoteInvocationHandler.java:215)
    at hudson.remoting.UserRequest.perform(UserRequest.java:114)
    at hudson.remoting.UserRequest.perform(UserRequest.java:48)
    at hudson.remoting.Request$2.run(Request.java:270)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:441)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)

I'm not sure, what this really means?

Version Number is Hudson ver. 1.373
I recently changed the Version Numbering Scheme in the pom.xml files maybe it has to do with it. I will check it.

Comment: Can you explain what your job setup is like? Do you have archiving of artifacts enabled? Did anything change within your job configuration recently? Have you upgraded your version of Hudson, and what version is it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found something on the hudson mailing list. http://hudson.361315.n4.nabble.com/Multimodule-build-hang-Unable-to-call-isArchivingDisabled-Invalid-object-ID-15-td2231235.html

For that guy is was a coding error in the test cases. So it would be a good idea to run the steps Hudson executes manually (outside of Hudson). If this doesn't fix your Problem, post the lines (more than one please) above your error message.

Comment: Problem has been solved, it was some configuration problem. Someone else changed it. Unfortunately I don't know the reason why this message occured. Thanks for your reply anyway.